# C# Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type. Generic Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, types, casting

For anyone who is experienced with C# this issue should be easy to fix. I want to make it so that subjects can have a list of courses. There are both tutor and students in this application. Thus, I created a generic Subject that defines the properties that both Tutor_Subject and Student_Subject implement. However I am getting a weird casting error.

```
public interface Subject<TCourse> where TCourse : Course
{
  int SubjectId { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }

  ICollection<TCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}

public partial class Student_Subject :Subject<Student_Course>
{
}

public partial class Tutor_Subject :Subject <Tutor_Course>
{
}

public interface Course
{
    int CourseId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Student_Course :Course
{
}

public partial class Tutor_Course :Course
{
}
```

Here is the issue

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Tutor_Subject' to 'Course'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
Subject<Course> subject;

if(type ==1)
{
    subject = new Student_Subject();  // Error 
    courseList = subjectInfo["courses"].ToObject<IList<Student_Course>>();
}
else
{
    subject = new Tutor_Subject();  // Error
    courseList = subjectInfo["courses"].ToObject<IList<Tutor_Course>>();
}

subject.Name = subjectName;
subject.Courses = courseList.ToList();
```

Comment: Well, what's the question? A `Student_Subject` is a `Subject<Student_Course>`, *not* a `Subject<Course>`, which `subject` is declared as.

Comment: I answered the question but I prefered to delete it because your question is unclear or its wrong naming convention creates a lot of confusion (interfaces are prefixed with `I` capital letter...) and I believe there're design flaws.

Comment: How can I have a subject Interface that is implemented by Student_Subject and Tutor_Subject which has a list of 'Course'. Course is a interface to be implemented by Student_Course and Tutor_Course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of C# 4, When using generics, you have to explicitly tell the compiler that a generic type may be of a more derived type (covariant) using the **out** keyword inside your generic parameter definition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

```
public interface Subject<out TCourse> where TCourse : Course
{
   int SubjectId { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<TCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I now understand how .Net is very type safe and need to specify the variance.  I am having one last issue now. I get a "Error 1 Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TCourse' must be invariantly valid on '<TCourse>.ICourses'. 'TCourse' is covariant". I tried changing ICollection<TCourse> ICourses to ICollection<out TCourse> ICourses but I have no luck.

Comment: Replace your ICollection<T> with IEnumerable<T>

Comment: I did that now it says  "Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TCourse' must be Contravariantly valid on '<TCourse>.ICourses'. 'TCourse' is covariant". Here is what I have so far               public interface ISubject<out TCourse > where TCourse : ICourse <TCourse>{....        IEnumerable<TCourse> ICourses { get; set; }.....}
  .......   Than I have ......
    public interface ICourse <out TCourse>

Comment: You cant have a getter and setter as your collection cant be covariant and contravariant at the same time (out and in).

Comment: Read this post by Eric Lippert on variance validity: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/03/exact-rules-for-variance-validity.aspx